# How can I use pyserial with python3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-3.4, pyserial

I am using pycharm, to create a user interface for a serial application I am writing, usinig python3.4 and tkinter.  The serial library, pyserial is (AFAIK)
only available in python 2.7. And tkinter, throws an error when I try to use python2.7. module not found, no module with that name.

At the beginning of a new project, PyCharm allows you to select a version of python to use, but evidently I can't select both at the same time.

How can I use tkinter, and pyserial in the same script and not get errors?
is there a version of pyserial for python3.4? how can I write python3.4 scripts and use pyserial?

Comment: pyserial does work with python3.4, on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial you can download a windows installer or the tarball. On debian/ubuntu you can just `apt-get install python3-serial`.

Comment: @j0h: I am using pycharm and tkinter with python 3.4.I want to work with serial library but I am not able to get exact syntax for including in program.